# "Permission denied: '/dev/ttyUSB0'" despite being already a member of 'dialout'

Tags: ubuntu, port, permission-denied

I am trying to connect an EPS WROOM 32 board to my computer and compiling some example of ESP-IDF projects provided from [the main website](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/tree/2f8b6cfc77bdb2c5c412f17529d5fddf9b68b325/examples).

However, I always get this error message:

> [Errno 13] could not open port /dev/ttyUSB0: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/dev/ttyUSB0'

And when I try to add my username to the *dialout* group, I get this message:

```
The user `myusername' is already a member of `dialout'
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Did you logout and login after changing your user group, this might sound silly if you already did this, but it's frequently forgotten.

Comment: That was really the Problem XD thanks for saving my day!

Comment: @Ferrybig It would be better if one of you added this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Reboot your computer.  Or log out and log back in.